# How to horizontally align card elements (rmwc) in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In my parent component:

```
        {
          this.state.projectList.map(dat => <Item data = {dat}/>)
        }
```

in the child component `Item`

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={{'width':'100%', 'textAlign':'center'}}>
            <Card style={{ width: '25rem', padding: '1rem', display: 'inline-block' }}>
                <CardPrimaryAction>
                    <div style={{ padding: '0 1rem 1rem 1rem' }}>
                    <Typography use="headline6" tag="h2">
                        {this.props.data.name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography use="body1" tag="div" theme="text-secondary-on-background">
                        {this.props.data.description}
                    </Typography>
                    </div>
                </CardPrimaryAction>
            </Card>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I am using the `rmwc` `Card` component to put some stuff.

[image]

Right now it just puts all rendered items vertically like a stack. What I actually want is the small sketch in a blue pen on the right side of the image.

I tried to give the wrapping `div` `'width':'100%', 'textAlign':'center'` and the `Card` itself an `inline-block` but it's still the same.

Comment: i think class **row** of parent tag and class col-md-3(1-12)  in it can help you to align component horizontally .

Answer (score 1):

**In parent component** enclose your map function with [`GridList`](https://material-ui.com/api/grid-list/) component of material-ui specifying the required columns. Then enclose your data in [`GridListTile`](https://material-ui.com/api/grid-list-tile). This is shown below,

```
 <div>
      <GridList cols={2} spacing={16}>
        this.state.projectList.map(dat => 
          <GridListTile item key={dat} xs={6}> 
            <Item data = {dat}/>
          <GridListTile/>
       ))}
     </GridList>
 </div>
```

**In child component**, remove the parent `<div>` and you are good to go.
*Please do import necessary dependencies.*